# (React JS Hooks issue) React JS only render posts from logged in user

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

**Problem**

I am new to React and am trying to build an application whereby logged in users can view posts they have created. I am having issues with asynchronous functions causing variables to be accessed before they are loaded in. I am using a Firestore database.

**Code**

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZAnibwI9u8&t=1657s) to set up authentication. I have created an `AuthContext.js` file, which contains this code (reduced):

```
const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    
    // const googleSignIn = () => {...}
    // const logOut = () => {...}

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
            setUser(currentUser);
        }); 
        return () => {
            unsubscribe();
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ googleSignIn, logOut, user }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
};

export const UserAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

I then wrap my application with a `AuthContextProvider` component and import `UserAuth` into any component that I want to be able to access the `user` object from. I have a `PostPage` component, and in it I want to ONLY render posts created by the logged in user. Each post has a `user` property containing the uid of the author. Here is my code:

```
import { UserAuth } from './context/AuthContext'

const PostsPage = () => {
    const { user } = UserAuth();
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    const postsRef = collection(db, 'posts');
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            if (user) {
                const q = query(postsRef, where('user', '==', user.uid));

                const data = await getDocs(q);
                const filtered = data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));
                setPosts(filtered);
            }
        } 

        return () => {
            getData();
        }
    }, [user]);

    return (
        // Display posts
    )
}

export default PostsPage;
```

Upon immediately refreshing the page, `getData` is executed. However, the code wrapped in the if statement does not run because the user has not yet been loaded in. Yet despite the dependancy array, `getData` is not executed again once the user data loads in, and I can't figure out why. If I render the user's uid, e.g. `<p>{ user.uid }</p>`, it will soon appear on the screen after the data has been loaded. But, I cannot figure out how to trigger `getData` after the user has been loaded. Any help with this would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue just because you put `getData()` call to the cleanup function of a hook. Cleanup function will execute on depsArray change but it will be executed with old data, closure captured. So when user changes from undefined => any - getUser will be called and will still have a closure-captured user set to undefined. You can clear the array instead in it, so if user logs out - dont show any messages

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    if (!user) return;
    const q = query(postsRef, where("user", "==", user.uid));

    const data = await getDocs(q);
    const filtered = data.docs.map((doc) => ({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id
    }));
    setPosts(filtered);
  };

  getData().catch(console.error);

  return () => {
    setPosts([]);
  };
}, [user]);
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I didn't know that the cleanup function was executed with old data!